# Simplify $\log(α+ b(x- t)+ k)$

Tags: logarithms

I am trying to simplify this natural log expression the best that I can, but I am unsure what to do in order to separate $b(x-t)$. Would it be $\log(b) + \log (x/t)$? so would the whole thing be:

$$ \log (\alpha + b) + \log (x/t) + \log k \quad?$$

Thank you!

Comment: Logs don’t work well with sums. $$\log(ab) = \log a+\log b \neq \log(a+b)$$ $$\log \frac{a}{b} = \log a-\log b \neq \log(a-b)$$

Answer (score 0):

No.  You can't separate $log(A+B)$ into two logarithms, no matter what $A$ and $B$ are.  The only things you can separate are $\log(AB)=\log(A)+\log(B)$, $\log_B(A)=\frac{\log(A)}{\log(B)}$ and $\log(A^B)=B\log(A)$, and their inverse operations

Answer (score 0):

You can only write $$\log(\alpha+bx-bt+k)$$ it holds only
$$\log(ab)=\log(a)+\log(b)$$ and $$\log\frac{a}{b}=\log(a)-\log(b)$$ for positive variables $a,b$